# Python3: Ambiguous error when starting dask.distributed.worker_client from other worker_client

Tags: python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed

I have code which I am trying to speed up using dask.disributed in Python3. I have a 3-level approach, where I have a dask.distributed `Client` object start a job. From within that job, I start `worker_clients` to run certain functions. Those `worker_clients` themselves start new `worker_clients`. So the heirarchy looks like

```
     level 0:                 Client 
                                /|\
     level 1:           wcA1    wcA2    wcA3     
                         /|\    /|\      /|\
     level 2:         wcB1 ...  wcB4...  wcB7...
```

I get the error message

`<Thread(Dask-Worker-Threads'-7805-1, started daemon 140437285209856)>`

with no further detail.

**What I have already tried:**

- skipping `level 1`. I can run this successfully with only two levels, a `Client` which starts `worker_clients`. The error occurs when I have a `worker_client` start other `worker_clients`.

**Code:**

- to start main `Client`: `cli = Client()`
- to start level1 and level2 `worker_clients`:

```py
with worker_client() as wc:
    y = [wc.submit(func, i) for i in iterable]
    y = wc.gather(y)
```

Does anyone have any input? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's going on here, but one thought from this line:

```
<Thread(Dask-Worker-Threads'-7805-1, started daemon 140437285209856)>
```

Is that maybe you've run out of threads?  Some operating systems only allow you to have a few thousand concurrent threads active at once.  I don't know what your problem is and if you might be near that limit, but you would know more.